# From where the user is coming, asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am creating a website and I want to know that user is coming from where, like from google, bing, asp.net, any other site. Is their any way to find out in asp.net ??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`Request.UrlReferrer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx) for this.

Comment: That is what I like about StackOverflow !!!!
Instant response. I am using Request.UrlReferrer. I'll deployed my website and respond to you asap.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
sPreviousURL = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER")
```

Comment: Can I use this in class instead of a page ??

As I have tried to implement it by inherting my class with System.Web.Ui.Page, But I am getting error.

Answer (score 2):

```
Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri;
```